# When I click outside the `<html>`, why does it trigger the click event bound on `<html>`?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

```js
const html = document.querySelector('html')
const body = document.querySelector('body')

body.onclick = () => {
  console.log('body clicked')
}

html.onclick = () => {
  console.log('html clicked')
}

document.onclick = (e) => {
  console.log('document clicked')
}

window.onclick = () => {
  console.log('window clicked')
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 20px solid red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
body {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 20px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

[image]

I have assigned a fixed width and height to the `<html>`(See the red box in the figure above.), When I click outside the red box, why does it trigger the click event bound on `<html>`?

Answer (score 0):

> When I click outside the red box, why does it trigger the click event
> bound on ?

You've really clicked outside *the red box*, but it still relates to `html` tag. It means: the position where you're clicking on, it's still inside `html` tag.

You can use Dev tools to check that:

[image: 1]

By hovering on `html` tag, you will see the real width/height of `html` tag is still full of the page.

Comment: The yellow area is the margin, and If the browser's viewing area is large enough, when hovering on `html` tag, you can see the white area below